# Ambiguous method call Both assertEquals(Object, Object) in Assert and assertEquals(double, double) in Assert match:

Tags: java, object, junit, double, assert

I am getting the following error:

```
Both assertEquals(Object, Object) in Assert and assertEquals(double, double) in Assert match
```

For this line of code in my `Junit` tests, note that `getScore`() returns a `double`:

```
assertEquals(2.5, person.getScore());
```

This is my assert import:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

What is causing this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your getScore() returns `Double`, not `double`. Therefore compiler is confused: Should it convert both arguments to Object, or if it should convert only the Double to double?

```
    double a = 2.0;
    Double b = 2.0;
    // assertEquals(a,b); // fails to compile
    // the compiler is confused whether to use
    assertEquals((Object) a,(Object) b); // OK
    // or
    assertEquals(a,(double) b); // OK
```

Anyway, I would set the method to return primitive type double.

Answer (score 9):

If you specifically interested in using `Assert.assertEquals(double, double)` (the primitive version), try calling overridden method that allows deviation and setting allowed deviation to zero, like this:

```
assertEquals(2.5, person.getScore(), 0.0);
```

You might also want to have third parameter to be something other than zero if `person.getScore()` is allowed to be slightly different from `2.5`. For example, if `2.500001` is acceptable, then your test becomes

```
assertEquals(2.5, person.getScore(), 0.000001);
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as it does explain the alternative as well as avoiding type cast.

Comment: @MohammadAdnan I don't think that this suggests a universal solution that doesn't involve type casting.

Comment: @RomeoSierra Please add why do you think it is not a better answer than above.

Comment: @MohammadAdnan I can give you a counter example. What about `assertEquals(Long expected, Long actual)`? I don't think you have a way around type casting in that case...

Comment: @RomeoSierra, if you have two objects of `Long`, the compiler will resolve to the closest type of `assertEquals(Object, Object)`. If one of those is primitive `long`, then there's indeed no way to avoid a type cast - however, the quesion was about `double`s, not `long`s.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Well, I have seen otherwise. I have had this exact problem with `Long`, which is how I stumbled upon this question. I am not saying that this is **not a solution**. It does solve the problem. What I am suggesting is that this is **not a universal solution**.

Comment: @RomeoSierra, it is *a solution* for problem of ambiguous selection between `assertEquals(Object, Object)` and `assertEquals(double, double)`. It is not a solution for ambiguous selection between `assertEquals(Object, Object)`, and `assertEquals(long, long)` (which is in fact its own separate problem entirely) - mainly because there's no method that would accept 3 args. If by "universal" you mean a solution to any kind of problem that involves ambiguous method select, then you are right - in fact, there is **no such solution in existence**, most similar problems are different enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically want to avoid casting AND use the primitive version, you can get the primitive result from a wrapper object. For example:

```
    double a = 2.0;
    Double b = 2.0;
    assertEquals(a, b.doubleValue()); //Deprecated so use the one with delta

    Integer c = 2;
    int d = 2;
    assertEquals(c.intValue(), d);

    Long e = 2L;
    long f = 2L;
    assertEquals(e.longValue(), f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I changed from this:

```
assertEquals("Server status code is: " +  wmResp.getStatusCode() , 200, wmResp.getStatusCode());
```

To this

```
assertEquals("Server status code is: " +  wmResp.getStatusCode() , Integer.valueOf(200), wmResp.getStatusCode());
```

This is happening because the first line compiler takes the 200 as primitive (integer not Integer class)

Comment: We shouldn't suggest people to use constructors of `Integer` and other similar wrapper types. It is marked as deprecated since Java 9, since Java 16 it is [marked for removal](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/390), and quite soon the constructors will be removed.

Comment: Thank you @Prokhorov   Spot on! fixed.