# Method assertEquals(Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type?

Tags: java, junit

My code snippet looks like this

```
@Test
public void testAddAndGet1() {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    list.add(42);
    list.add(-3);
    list.add(17);
    list.add(99);
    assertEquals(42, list.get(0));
    assertEquals(-3, list.get(1));
    assertEquals(17, list.get(2));
    assertEquals(99, list.get(3));

    assertEquals("second attempt", 42, list.get(0));   // make sure I can get them a second time
    assertEquals("second attempt", 99, list.get(3));
}
```

I am receiving `Method assertEquals(Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type`. I am not sure why I am getting it?

Comment: please include your import section.

Comment: Have you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811103/java-junit-the-method-x-is-ambiguous-for-type-y)? their your error is broken down and explained.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java JUnit: The method X is ambiguous for type Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811103/java-junit-the-method-x-is-ambiguous-for-type-y)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have got this error because you trying to compare two different type (int,Integer) try to cast one of the parameter

Maybe this post can helps you:
[Ambiguous method call Both assertEquals(Object, Object) in Assert and assertEquals(double, double) in Assert match:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893633/ambiguous-method-call-both-assertequalsobject-object-in-assert-and-assertequa)

Answer (score 0):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

//import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

//import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test; (make this out by commenting then this works fine i just tested now)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).